# Pixelated external monitor image through USB-C to DisplayPort cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics, displayport, hardware-recommendation

This is what my external monitor shows with my new 16-inch mac (2019) through a usb-c to displayport cable. It's a really grainy texture.

[image]

Whereas this is what my external monitor shows with my old macbook air (2012) through a mini displayport to DVI cable.
[image]

Zoom in **just a little bit** if you can't see the difference.

However, when I connected my android Samsung smartphone to the display with this same usb-c to displayport cable, the picture quality was superb.

I'm wondering what I should do. Get a new cable? Because the one I have isn't compatible with macOS for example? Or the hardware of my Mac?

It looks like this is a problem for the newer butterfly keyboard macs. Those after 2015. I've seen others on some forums with the same issue. Perhaps my external monitor (LG 27EA83) isn't compatible with the new macs? Or it doesn't work well through usb-c?

Comment: Font smoothing is enabled for both. And both are at the same resolution, 2560x1440

Comment: They look virtually identical

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: How can the cable be faulty if you connect it with a different device and the picture quality is “superb?”  You’ve effectively diagnosed and narrowed the issue to your a MBP.  Have you tried changing your display settings?

Comment: I think this might be a issue of different color profiles being applied to the display, rather than a matter of pixilation. I suggest you open System Preferences->Displays->Color on both machines and compare the settings.